# With http.server how to access the called IP address?

Tags: python-3.x, http

This must be very simple, but can't find any reference on documentation and google isn't helping.
On the below example

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

PORT_NUMBER = 80

class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        print(self.path)   # <<<<<<<< Here
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("Hello world", "utf8"))

server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

If my machine has multiple interfaces, the binding is done with 0.0.0.0. How can I on the request handler retrieve the IP which was received the socket connection ?

Comment: I don't have a multi-IP box to test on, but what does `self.request.getsockname()` get you?

Comment: Yes! That was it, or to be more precise self.request.getsockname()[0] for the IP only. Not sure of the best practices in this case to vote "your comment up", but think the question is answered.

Comment: I turned it into an answer with a little more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `do_*` methods of an instance of `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`, `self.request` is the [`socket.socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket) object associated with the request. You can get the server side of the socket with [`self.request.getsockname()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getsockname), which will give you a tuple of the server IP and port that the client connected to. Therefore the IP address will be:

```
self.request.getsockname()[0]
```